# Image loading performance in accordance to its dimensions

Tags: html

Is this true that image whose dimensions are:

```
2x2 | 4x4 | 8x8 | 16x16 | 32x32 | 64x64 | 128x128 | 256x256 | 512x512

// so on . . . .
```

and so on are easier to load and for displaying? I read somewhere that computer like these dimensions and perform very well. Does it also apply in HTML documents? If it is so, we should make icons and all that stuff in `16x16` and `32x32` ?

Comment: hey man i am making icons if i make it like 48x48 then if 32x32 increases performance then why should i resize and waste my all work. Resizing make images pixelated a little.

Answer (score 1):

While it may be true elsewhere (like for Favicons, see below), it is not the case for normal images in HTML documents. A HTML image can have whatever dimensions you want it to have.

For optimum performance, make sure that the image's physical size is identical with the size of the HTML `image` tag, so the browser doesn't have to do any resizing.

> If it is so, we should make icons and all that stuff in 16x16 and 32x32 ?

[Favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) should come in certain, defined sizes.

Inside the HTML document though, the only reasons to have an image 16x16 instead of 17x17 pixels are design considerations. It's definitely got nothing to do with performance.

Comment: ahh, I thought when i was learning game development, the person whose tutorials i was following, said sprites should be like that so, I think it will also apply HTML documents.

Comment: So, you wanna say that I jump in, make icons in any size and apply them ?

Comment: Sprites kind of change the question IMHO, as they do indeed give a performance increase since the browser only has to load one image instead of many.

Comment: @ajp15243 yeah i know that sprites will help me in increasing performance [just was searching and got it] and i am satisfied with Pekka :D thanks everybody. Oh sorry, in my above comment i wrote sprites instead of textures. Noticed it now ;)